# How to simulate click event in View/Display for test purpose?

Tags: java, gwt, testing, mvp

The section on [GWT testing](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture#testing) describes how to verify output of `Presenter` in `Display` object, but does not explain how to do the other way around. In other words, I want to check whether `Presenter` will make a correct request to `RPC Service` when a user clicks button in `Display`.

How can I simulate button click in `Display`? Firing GWT events is not straightforward, as they have protected constructors. Is there a way to do it simply, without subclassing `ClickEvent` class?

```
@Before
protected void setUp() {
    mockRpcService = mock(NegotiationServiceAsync.class);
    eventBus = new HandlerManager(null);
    mockDisplay = mock(NegotiationPresenter.Display.class);
    negotiationPresenter = new NegotiationPresenter(mockRpcService,
            eventBus, mockDisplay);
}

@Test
private void testSth() {        
    when(mockDisplay.getSuppliersEmails()).thenReturn("address@domain.com");
    when(mockDisplay.getTaskDescription()).thenReturn("This is the task to do");

    // This does not work
    mockDisplay.getSubmitButton().fireEvent(new ClickEvent());      

    verify(mockRpcService).startTask(any(NegotiationRequest.class), any(AsyncCallback.class));      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use MVP you normally test methods in the presenter injecting a mocked implementation of the view, so in your test the display does nothing, just offers stub methods to the presenter. 
In the other hand, your real display implementation should delegate all actions to the presenter.

The way to test the behavior of your presenter when a user clicks on the submit button is calling the method in the presenter, something like this:

```
@Test
private void testSth() {        
  when(mockDisplay.getSuppliersEmails()).thenReturn("address@domain.com");
  when(mockDisplay.getTaskDescription()).thenReturn("This is the task to do");

  negotiationPresenter.onSubmit();

  verify(mockRpcService).startTask(any(NegotiationRequest.class),
                                   any(AsyncCallback.class));      
}
```

A very different case is if you wanted to test your code using GWTTestCase so as you could use real view implementations, but in this case your tests would last a long, loosing one of the main goals of using MVP, which is, to decouple the view to test the main app code which is supposed to be in Presenters and classes which can be run in the JVM.

Comment: +1 Your answer solves the problem. Can you recommend a tutorial for proper testing of GWT apps? Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) is quite misleading here. First, handling methods like `onSubmit()` are made private in Presenter, thus hindering testing. Second, Presenter knows about `ClickEvent` that belongs to GWT package, while it should rather receive `SubmitEvent' that would make Presenter testable.

Comment: Dont pass the event to the presenter. In the view you should have something like this: `submitButton(new ClickEvent()){presenter.submit()}`. In the presenter you call to the view to get values: `public submit(){ view.getWhatever() ... }`. So as you can see the view uses the presenter to call methods when an event if fired, and the presenter gets and sets values from the view. A common practice to test methods is to make them protected and use the name namespace for the test class. Have yo read [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt) ?